# Docker user Permission denied on accessing folder in container

Tags: django, ubuntu, docker, pip, docker-compose

I am running `docker-compose` to bring together django with a few other services with the following config:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.10
FROM python:3.5.0

ENV EXTRACTOR_SRC=.
ENV EXTRACTOR_SRVHOME=/srv
ENV EXTRACTOR_SRVPROJ=/srv/extractor_django

#Install package dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip virtualenvwrapper

# Create application subdirectories
WORKDIR $EXTRACTOR_SRVHOME
RUN mkdir media static logs
VOLUME ["$EXTRACTOR_SRVHOME/media/", "$EXTRACTOR_SRVHOME/logs/"]

# Copy application source code to SRCDIR
COPY $EXTRACTOR_SRC $EXTRACTOR_SRVPROJ

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install -r $EXTRACTOR_SRVPROJ/requirements.txt

# create user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' dockeruser
```

**(Relevant) Docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'

services:

  # Django web server
  web:
     build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
     hostname: web
     command: /srv/www/run_web.sh
     volumes:
          - .:/srv/www
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
```

**run_web.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o verbose

sleep 15
cd /srv/extractor_django

su -m dockeruser -c "python manage.py makemigrations"
su -m dockeruser -c "python manage.py migrate"
su -m dockeruser -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

# Start Gunicorn processes
echo Starting Gunicorn.

su -m dockeruser -c "gunicorn extractorService.wsgi:application \
    --name extractor_django \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --workers 10 \
    --log-level=info"
```

During runtime one of the python requirements (spacy) tries to store and access files in a restricted folder causing the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:       
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/data'
```

Is there a way I can give the dockeruser sufficient privileges that would work. Alternatively would it be more sensible to run this with virtualenv as the issue seems to be access to the system wide python folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can just solve this in the ways that you would solve it outside of Docker. Either give that user the appropriate permissions over that folder / structure, or as you say you can use a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give extended privileges to the container with `privileged` option?

```
version: '2'

services:

  # Django web server
  web:
     build:
         privileged: true
         context: .
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
     hostname: web
     command: /srv/www/run_web.sh
     volumes:
          - .:/srv/www
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
```